# Django REST Framework Specify Some Fields Before calling serializer.isValid()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to set some fields (that don't come over as JSON in the request.  How do I do so with the Django REST framework.

```
    serializer = GoalSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    serializer.status = 'I' ##IS THIS RIGHT????????????????
    serializer.journal = id

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I do this because status and journal (which is a foreign key field) are required.  But always get 400 response.  Is this the right way to set those fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to access:

```
serializer.object
```

That is the object that you are going to be saving to the database when when calling:

```
serializer.save()
```

So if you are setting extra fields on you Model object before saving it to the database, then you would want to do:

```
serializer.object.status = "I"
serializer.object.journal = id
```